# Store 3x3 matrix in a variable in a for loop

Tags: matlab

I have a 9x3 matrix that I subdivided into three (3) 3x3 matrix. Now I want to make a for loop function that will store each 3x3 matrix into a variable.

```
X=reshape(1:27,3,9)';          % sample 9x3 matrix
xx = mat2cell(X,[3,3,3],3);    % subdivide X matrix into 3x3 cell matrix
for i:1:3
  x(i) = xx{i,1}; %store the three cells into x1 x2 and x3 matrix
end
```

I know that this does not how it works in matlab but just to show the function I would like to attain.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to do this. What do you want to do which requires multiple variables?

Comment: What I wish to achieve is,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` function.

```
X=reshape(1:27,3,9)';          % sample 9x3 matrix
xx = mat2cell(X,[3,3,3],3);    % subdivide X matrix into 3x3 cell matrix
for i=1:3
  eval(['x' num2str(i) ' = xx{' num2str(i) ',1};']);
end
```

But **What you are asking for** is not recommended at all. In fact i always avoid using `eval` because the code doesn't get checked by MATLAB editor.

It is also not a good idea to have multiple variables, instead use cells, structures, and so on for a better usage in the rest of your code.

Comment: If it's not recommended please don't even suggest it.

Comment: @Suever What is asked in the question itself is not recommended, and that is why i have to answer with a not recommended one. by the way the code totally works. I have edited my answer too, to reflect this.

Comment: Whether it works or not is not the issue. You could at least offer some alternatives.

Comment: Got it working! I would like to accept your recommendation that is not a good way to implement. If i may ask, what would be the best approach for this? If you could show me a code using the same matrix in the example.

Comment: @AOmisol Please see my answer below for a fast way to store this within a 3D array that is more performance and preferred.

Comment: @Suever . I can offer alternatives only if i know the intention of user who asked the question. Because depending on what he is trying to do next, different approaches may be used.

Comment: @AOmisol Please let me know what are you going to do next. You should also mention if performance does matter, and if your matrices in the real application are big or small. The solution which Suever proposed is good in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
X=reshape(1:27,3,9)';
for i=1:3
    block = X(3*i-2:3*i,:);
    disp(block);    
end
```

Comment: It do separate! But the block value is equal to the last 3x3 matrix. I would like to use block1, block2, block3 matrix for different calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to do this is to actually just store it in a 3D array and you can access each element along the third dimension. The reason for that is that MATLAB is optimized for computing using matrices, so if you keep all of your data in a matrix, operations can be performed in a vectorized fashion on all components.

Better yet you can remove the `for` loop needed to create it by using `reshape` and `permute`.

```
X = permute(reshape(X', [3 3 3]), [2 1 3]);

% And access each element
X(:,:,1)
X(:,:,2)
X(:,:,3)
```

This is going to be more performance than using cell arrays or `eval`.

Comment: Got it! I will study on the permute function. But I get to understand now why it is more efficient.

Comment: All that `permute` does here is transposes each 3d "slice"